[gazebo_ros2_control]: parser error Couldn't parse parameter override rule
I am new to ROS2 and I encounter some strange parsing error when I try to launch my gazebo simulation.
I am using ROS2 Iron on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM
Here is my project repository
That repo works fine since I am following this tutorial series and I have the same robot model as the tutorial. The issue is that as soon as I change the robot_base.xacro errors pop up
new robot_base.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" >

<xacro:include filename="inertial_macros.xacro" />

<material name="white">
    <color rgba="1 1 1 1" />
</material>

<material name="orange">
    <color rgba= "1 0.3 0.1 1"/>
</material>

<material name="blue">
    <color rgba="0.2 0.2 1 1"/>
</material>

<material name="black">
    <color rgba="0 0 0 1"/>
</material>

<material name="red">
    <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
</material>

                                                <!-- BASE LINK -->

<link name="base_link">

</link>

                                                <!-- CHASSIS LINK -->

<!-- dimensiuni sasiu: 780x600mm 
    dimensiune profil: 40x40mm
    L profil: 700mm
    l profil: 600mm
    Distanta mijloc sasiu - centru roti: 43.5mm
-->
<joint name="chassis_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="chassis"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.39 0 0.0435"/>
</joint>

<link name="chassis">
    <visual> <!-- Back Profile -->
        <origin xyz="0.02 0 0"/> 
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.04 0.6 0.04"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <visual> <!-- Front Profile -->
        <origin xyz="0.76 0 0"/> 
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.04 0.6 0.04"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="white"/>
    </visual>
    <visual> <!-- Right Profile -->
        <origin xyz="0.39 0.28 0"/> 
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.7 0.04 0.04"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <visual> <!-- Left Profile -->
        <origin xyz="0.39 -0.28 0"/> 
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.7 0.04 0.04"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision> <!-- Colision -->
        <origin xyz="0.39 0 0"/> 
        <geometry>
            <box size="0.78 0.6 0.04"/> 
        </geometry>
    </collision>
                <!-- Inertia -->
    <xacro:inertial_hollow_frame mass="3.224" x="0.78" y="0.6" z="0.04">
        <origin xyz="0.39 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    </xacro:inertial_hollow_frame>
</link>

<gazebo reference="chassis">
    <material>Gazebo/White</material>
</gazebo>

                                                <!-- RIGHT WHEEL LINK -->

<joint name="right_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="right_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0 -0.2125 0" rpy="${pi/2} 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 -1"/>
</joint>

<link name="right_wheel">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.04"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="orange"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.05"/> 
        </geometry>
    </collision>
                <!-- Inertia -->
    <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.04" radius="0.05">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
</link>

<gazebo reference="right_wheel">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
</gazebo>

                                                <!-- LEFT WHEEL LINK -->

<joint name="left_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="left_wheel"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0.2125 0" rpy="-${pi/2} 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<link name="left_wheel">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <cylinder radius="0.05" length="0.04"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="orange"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.05"/> 
        </geometry>
    </collision>
                <!-- Inertia -->
    <xacro:inertial_cylinder mass="0.1" length="0.04" radius="0.05">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_cylinder>
</link>

<gazebo reference="left_wheel">
    <material>Gazebo/Orange</material>
</gazebo>

                                                <!-- CASTER WHEEL LINKS -->
<!--
    distanta centru roata - profil superior: 77.75mm 
    distanta X si Y centru roata - margine profil: 94.75mm
    distanta roti L: 590.50mm
    distanta roti l: 410.50mm
-->

    <!-- Caster wheel 1 -->
<joint name="caster_wheel_1_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="caster_wheel_1"/>
    <origin xyz="0.09475 0.20525 -0.05"/>
</joint>

<link name="caster_wheel_1">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <!-- Inertia -->
    <xacro:inertial_sphere mass="0.1" radius="0.03775">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_sphere>
</link>

<gazebo reference="caster_wheel_1">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    <mu1 value="0.001"/>
    <mu2 value="0.001"/>
</gazebo>

        <!-- Caster wheel 2 -->
<joint name="caster_wheel_2_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="caster_wheel_2"/>
    <origin xyz="0.09475 -0.20525 -0.05"/>
</joint>

<link name="caster_wheel_2">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <!-- Inertia -->
    <xacro:inertial_sphere mass="0.1" radius="0.03775">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_sphere>
</link> 

<gazebo reference="caster_wheel_2">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    <mu1 value="0.001"/>
    <mu2 value="0.001"/>
</gazebo>

    <!-- Caster wheel 3 -->
<joint name="caster_wheel_3_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="caster_wheel_3"/>
    <origin xyz="0.68525 0.20525 -0.05"/>
</joint>

<link name="caster_wheel_3">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <!-- Inertia -->
    <xacro:inertial_sphere mass="0.1" radius="0.03775">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_sphere>
</link> 

<gazebo reference="caster_wheel_3">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    <mu1 value="0.001"/>
    <mu2 value="0.001"/>
</gazebo>

    <!-- Caster wheel 4 -->
<joint name="caster_wheel_4_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="chassis"/>
    <child link="caster_wheel_4"/>
    <origin xyz="0.68525 -0.20525 -0.05"/>
</joint>

<link name="caster_wheel_4">
    <visual>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
        <material name="black"/>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <geometry>
            <sphere radius="0.03775"/> 
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    <!-- Inertia -->
    <xacro:inertial_sphere mass="0.1" radius="0.03775">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </xacro:inertial_sphere>
</link> 

<gazebo reference="caster_wheel_4">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    <mu1 value="0.001"/>
    <mu2 value="0.001"/>
</gazebo>

After I launch launch_sim.launch.py with verbose set to true I get the following:
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/cosmin2/.ros/log/2024-05-03-22-59-12-824954-cosmin2-virtual-machine-13244
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [13247]
[INFO] [gzserver-2]: process started with pid [13249]
[INFO] [gzclient-3]: process started with pid [13253]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [13257]
[INFO] [spawner-5]: process started with pid [13266]
[INFO] [spawner-6]: process started with pid [13269]
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685402402] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685606128] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel_1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685624282] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel_2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685629840] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel_3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685634300] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment caster_wheel_4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685638681] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment chassis
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685642963] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment laser_frame
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685647412] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment left_wheel
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1714766353.685651823] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment right_wheel
[gzclient-3] Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
[gzclient-3] Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
[gzclient-3] Released under the Apache 2 License.
[gzclient-3] http://gazebosim.org
[gzclient-3] 
[gzserver-2] Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.2
[gzserver-2] Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
[gzserver-2] Released under the Apache 2 License.
[gzserver-2] http://gazebosim.org
[gzserver-2] 
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1714766354.846650665] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1714766354.847499410] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/iron/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rclpy/qos.py:313: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1714766354.851522390] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1714766354.864362381] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1714766354.865216983] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[gzserver-2] [Msg] Waiting for master.
[gzserver-2] [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[gzserver-2] [Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.137.133
[gzserver-2] [Err] [Server.cc:472] Could not open file[]
[gzserver-2] [Wrn] [Server.cc:381] Falling back on worlds/empty.world
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1714766355.625444755] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[gzclient-3] [Msg] Waiting for master.
[gzclient-3] [Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[gzclient-3] [Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.137.133
[gzclient-3] [Msg] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[gzclient-3] [Wrn] [Event.cc:61] Warning: Deleting a connection right after creation. Make sure to save the ConnectionPtr from a Connect call
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1714766355.998466139] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [my_bot]
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1714766356.002695081] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
[gzserver-2] [WARN] [1714766356.022324627] [rcl]: Found remap rule '~/out:=scan'. This syntax is deprecated. Use '--ros-args --remap ~/out:=scan' instead.
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1714766356.140084871] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading gazebo_ros2_control plugin
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1714766356.156231225] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in namespace: /
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1714766356.156629779] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Starting gazebo_ros2_control plugin in ros 2 node: gazebo_ros2_control
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1714766356.166773711] [gazebo_ros2_control]: connected to service!! robot_state_publisher
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1714766356.176026834] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Received urdf from param server, parsing...
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 13257]
[gzserver-2] [INFO] [1714766356.177329179] [gazebo_ros2_control]: Loading parameter files /home/cosmin2/test/install/amr_platform/share/amr_platform/config/my_controllers.yaml
[gzserver-2] [rcutils|error_handling.c:65] an error string (message, file name, or formatted message) will be truncated
[gzserver-2] [ERROR] [1714766356.177995399] [gazebo_ros2_control]: parser error Couldn't parse parameter override rule: '--param robot_description:=<?xml version="1.0" ?><!-- =================================================================================== --><!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from /home/cosmin2/test/install/amr_platform/share/amr_platform/description/robot.urdf.xacro | --><!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | --><!-- =================================================================================== --><robot name="robot"><!-- Specify some standard inertial calculations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia --><!-- These make use of xacro's mathematical functionality --><material name="white"><color rgba="1 1 1 1"/></material><mate, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:343
[gzserver-2] 
[gzclient-3] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy
[gzclient-3] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1714766356.832308955] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1714766356.840711631] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1714766358.844338192] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1714766358.850024120] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[gzserver-2] [Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/empty.world]
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1714766360.856146653] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1714766360.861986117] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-6] [INFO] [1714766362.866226563] [spawner_joint_broad]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [INFO] [1714766362.875041967] [spawner_diff_cont]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-5] [ERROR] [1714766364.887472807] [spawner_diff_cont]: Controller manager not available
[spawner-6] [ERROR] [1714766364.887747489] [spawner_joint_broad]: Controller manager not available
[ERROR] [spawner-6]: process has died [pid 13269, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/spawner joint_broad --ros-args'].
[ERROR] [spawner-5]: process has died [pid 13266, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/iron/lib/controller_manager/spawner diff_cont --ros-args'].

The issue is with:
[gzserver-2] [ERROR] [1714766356.177995399] [gazebo_ros2_control]: parser error Couldn't parse parameter override rule: '--param robot_description:=<?xml version="1.0" ?><!-- =================================================================================== --><!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from /home/cosmin2/test/install/amr_platform/share/amr_platform/description/robot.urdf.xacro | --><!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | --><!-- =================================================================================== --><robot name="robot"><!-- Specify some standard inertial calculations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia --><!-- These make use of xacro's mathematical functionality --><material name="white"><color rgba="1 1 1 1"/></material><mate, at ./src/rcl/arguments.c:343

Whatever I do I cannot manage to get rid of it. Tried to modify only a line of the working robot_base.xacro of the tutorial but as soon as I do that it breaks. The new robot_base.xacro that I want to use(the one from above) used to work just fine until a few weeks ago.

Maybe it is related to https://github.com/ros-controls/gazebo_ros2_control/issues/295, especially the deleting of colons helped in my case.

What do you mean by deleting of colons? For example i just take the original working model and only changing one digit of a random dimension makes it unusable.

In my case the deleting of colons inside of comments helps to get rid of the parsing error. In also did not change anything in my URDF. My assumption is that it has something to do with an update of the Humble package.

To be more precise, I meant to delete the colons inside the commments of the URDF
